# React api connection error

Tags: reactjs, api

hello i have a problem with react, i want to get the result from an api and show the infos but i get an error,
[error map undeff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1udu.png) can anyone help ?
connection is good but i can't map the result

```js
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {info: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.FlightList();
  }

  FlightList() {
    $.getJSON('api')
      .then(({ results }) => this.setState({ info: results }));
  }


  render() {
    let infos = this.state.info.map((item) => (
      <div>
        <h1>{item.flight.name}</h1>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
        <div className="panel-list">{ infos }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you print API response?

Comment: @Suresh Prajapati i added a picture

Comment: did u tried @San Phan Đình's answer?

Comment: @Suresh Prajapati yes but i still get the error

Comment: @helpcaller Did you try my answer , can you tell me what error do you get using it?

Comment: Can u log result inside function FlightList
FlightList() {
  $.getJSON('api').then(results => { console.log(results); this.setState({ info: results })});
}
Also u will have to bind this to function like
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {info: []};
    this.FlightList = this.FlightList.bind(this);
  }

Comment: did u able to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the data before the the api request has completed and the state is set because the component renders once before componentDidMount gets fired, that's why when you try to map over the state it throws an error as its empty. 
To solve this you need to wait for the data for example by maintaining a loading state like

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {info: [],isLoading:true};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.FlightList();
  }

  FlightList() {
    $.getJSON('api')
      .then(({ results }) => this.setState({ info: results,isLoading:false }));
  }


  render() {
    let infos=[]
    if(isLoading)  return <div>Loading data....</div>
    if(!isLoading){
      {infos = this.state.info.map((item) => (
      <div>
        <h1>{item.flight.name}</h1>
      </div>
    ))};

    return (
      <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
        <div className="panel-list">{ infos }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding FlightList in constructor. 
In constructor:

```
constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = {info: []}; this.FlightList = this.FlightList.bind(this);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need define the default state like

state = {info: []}

So when you try to map, it will not print error because we have defined default value for info in state.